# Template code and literal strings

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I am currently writing some template code where the template parameter is the char type to use. This causes a problem when referring to literal strings. I can, of course, make a struct with the strings I use but I was thinking if it would be possible to make something like:

```
template<typename chartype, char32_t... chars>
struct tr {
   /* some magic here */
};
```

so that `tr<char32_t,U"hello world">` would result in `U"hello world"`
and `tr<char16_t,U"Hello world">` would result in `u"hello world"`
and `tr<char,U"hello world">` would result in `"hello world"` (in UTF-8).

The magic should of course correctly translate codes above 0x10000 to lead code and follow code for char16_t and to proper 2, 3 and 4 byte codes for UTF-8
at compile time.

Problem is: how do you define a constant C-style string of a given char type using the `char32_t... chars` template argument? You can extract the characters
from it but how do you rebuild a new string based on the chars of the input string in template code?

Note, the preprocessor can correctly define a string such as `"hello world"` with suitable prefix u or U if you like but it cannot access the individual characters of the string to properly translate it.

EDIT:

Strings as template arguments are definitely possible in new C++, however,
the template argument is NOT declared as `const char *` or something like that:

```
template <char... txt>
struct foo { ... }
```

allows you to write `foo<"hello">` as a type with the string `"hello"` as template argument. The problem is how to build the string from those characters.

I mean at some point you want the struct to contain a string value to return:

```
   template <char32_t... txt>
   struct foo;

   template <>
   struct foo<> {
      static const char16_t * txt() { return ""; }
   };

   template <char32_t a, char32_t... rest>
   struct foo<a, rest...> {
   static const char16_t * txt()
   {
        char16_t buf[100];
        int k = 0;
        if (a < 0x10000) buf[k++] = a;
        else {
          buf[k++] = 0xd800 | ((a - 0x10000) >> 10);
          buf[k++] = 0xdc00 | ((a-0x10000) & 0x3ff);
        }
        // copy rest of string into buf + 2..99
        u16strcpy(buf + k, foo<rest...>::txt());
       return buf;
     }
   }
```

Several obvious problems with this "solution", one problem is that buf only have room for 100 characters which will fail if the string is longer. but the main problem is that I wanted this to happen in compile time and this looks very much like run time code to me and is not at all what I wanted to do.

Basically I wanted something that works this way:

`foo<char, "hello">` results in something that is effectively a string literal
`"hello"` or `u8"hello"`.

`foo<char16_t, "hello">` results in something that is effectively a string literal `u"hello"` and `foo<char32_t, "hello">` results in something that is effectively a string literal `U"hello"`.

The problem is when writing template code to handle various character formats and then having string literals involved. Yes, you can write a simple struct:

```
template <typename ChT> struct bar;
   template <>
   struct bar<char32_t> {
     static const char32_t * txta = U"AAAA";
     static const char32_t * txtb = U"BBBB";
   };
```

and so on and `bar<char16_t>` has `txta = u"AAAA"` etc. Then refer to the strings
in your templated code by `bar<T>::txta` etc. However, I wish there was a way that you could specify those strings directly in templated code and the compiler would do the right thing. A templated string literal in other words.

Maybe it should be added as a feature to the language that
`T<char32_t> string-literal` is the same as U string-literal etc
so that you could write

```
 template <typename ChT>
 struct foo {
    static const ChT * txta = T<ChT> "AAAAA";
 };
```

and the compiler would do the right thing.

Comment: I would use template'd inline function like:

    template<typename chartype>
    inline const chartype[] func(const char32_t hello_world[])

Comment: What about this: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Compile-Time-String-in-C-14-td4666747.html

Comment: Must `char32_t... chars` be used? what about `auto &chars`?

Comment: Where is using a string literal as a template argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter pack described in the Standard? I don't see anything about it in the current https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tools to make it work in **C++17** (might be portable to C++11 and C++14):

## `static constexpr` data member of templated class

The output literal you wish to work with needs some "storage". I suggest to instantiate a unique class template for each literal, e.g., `Literal<char, 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'>. That class can hold the data as a`static constexpr` member.

```
template<class C, C... cs>
struct Literal {
  static_assert(sizeof...(cs) >= 1);
  static constexpr C data[] = {cs...};// or use `std::array<C, sizeof...(cs)>`
};

template<class C, C... cs>
constexpr C Literal<C, cs...>::data[];
```

## user-defined string literal to simplify syntax

Of course you wish to avoid typing, e.g., `Literal<char, 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'>`. A useful tool to achieve that is the following overload for user-defined string literals.

```
template<class C, C... cs>
constexpr Literal<C, cs..., C('\0')> operator""_c() {// or use `auto`
  return Literal<C, cs..., C('\0')>{};
}
```

Note how the input literal is passed as non-type template parameters to that overload. That way, it is possible to "carry the value as a type".

## `constexpr` algorithms for re-encoding

So far, you can type `"foo"_c` to obtain a `Literal<char, 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'>` which has a `static constexpr` data member yielding the same as `"foo"`. Next you can pass that `Literal<char, 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'>` to a function which returns a `const char16_t(&)[4]` to `data` of the corresponding `Literal<char16_t, ..., '\0'>`. The syntax could read `tr<char16_t>("foo"_c)`.

The code that transforms a `Literal<char, ...>` into the corresponding `Literal<char16_t, ...>` may be based on `constexpr` algorithms as shown below.

```
template<
  class OutChar, class InChar, InChar... cs,
  std::size_t... input_indices, std::size_t... output_indices
>
constexpr auto& tr_impl(// called by `tr` with appropriate `index_sequence`s
  Literal<InChar, cs...>,
  std::index_sequence<input_indices...>,
  std::index_sequence<output_indices...>
) {
  constexpr std::size_t outsize = sizeof...(output_indices);

  using Buffer = std::array<OutChar, outsize>;
  constexpr Buffer buf = encode_as<OutChar, outsize>({cs...});

  return Literal<OutChar, buf[output_indices]...>::data;
}

template<class OutChar, class InChar, InChar... cs>
constexpr auto& tr(Literal<InChar, cs...> literal) {
  constexpr std::size_t outsize = count_as<OutChar>({cs...});

  return tr_impl<OutChar>(
    literal,
    std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(cs)>{},// input indices
    std::make_index_sequence<outsize>{}// output indices
  );
}
```

The remaining part would be to implement those functions `count_as` and `encode_as`.

## assign to `constexpr auto&` in final usage

Finally you can assign to `constexpr auto&` to verify that type and value are equivalent to the plain string literal based on the desired character type.

```
  static_assert(std::size(U"") == 3);
  static_assert(std::size(u"") == 5);

  constexpr auto& test = tr<char16_t>(U""_c);
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(test), const char16_t(&)[5]>{});

  for(std::size_t i=0; i<std::size(u""); ++i) {
    assert(test[i] == u""[i]);
    std::cout << i << ": " << test[i] << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: It is so disappointing that in 2024 we still have this same problem. It is pretty obvious to me that the problem is the fact that there is not string in C++... there is only pointer to char. In case of a string-literal in a template, the string literal should be considered as its contents, not as a pointer. This hack described here is a way to realize the string as its contents, not its pointer. Instead of hacks (what they are trying to do to fix this in the standards), there should be a "string-literal type", to be used only in templates, that could be converted to a pointer non-uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to simply not be legal, even the following is rejected (vs2017, with standard set to latest):

```
template<char const * ptr>
struct test
{};
void bar()
{
  test<"testing"> t;
}
```

with the error: invalid expression as a template argument for 'ptr', and if that's not going to work trying to convert it at compile-time is a non-starter. And honestly this doesn't seem all that surprising that a pointer-to-data isn't constant enough. to be a template argument.